# How to Exclusively Select Radio Buttons if name attribute is deprecated?

Tags: html

I learned that the `name` attribute has been deprecated. But this is how I performed exclusive selection of radio buttons on the form. How do I do it now without using JavaScript?

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</input>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Undo your belief that the name attribute is deprecated.

[Name is deprecated on a, applet, frame, iframe, img and map but not on input](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the `name` attribute is not deprecated in general, only for certain elements, [namely `a, applet, form, frame, iframe, img,` and `map`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10). For those, you're supposed to use the `id` attribute instead. For input elements, using `name` is still correct.

Answer (score -1):

I simply use jQuery and give all radio elements in same group some class. That way I can select elements with $("input.classname").